# XHR Object's message is undefined but shows the correct status

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm making an ajax call that the response would be a 400 http error code.
I'm using php as the serverside language.
My php :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html',true,400);
echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
```

my javascript:

```
$('#upload-form').ajaxForm({
            success: function() {
                $(".loader").hide();
                return false;
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                var imageUrls = new Array();
                var i = 0;
                jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    imageUrls[i] = item.name.toString();
                    i++;
                });
                alert(imageUrls);
                $(".loader").hide();
                return false;
            },
            error : function(xhr, status, errorMessage) {
                //alert(xhr.status);
                alert(status);
                alert(errorMessage);
                //$("#status").html(xhr.message);
                $(".loader").hide();
            }
        });
```

when I want to show error message, it returns undefined. I've used `xhr` and `xhr.message` but no luck. How can I return an error code with a message to an ajax call and proccess the response?

Comment: ... you are using `jQuery.each(data,` but data isn't defined.

Comment: Try logging the other two parameters sent to the error callback. `error : function(xhr, status, errorMessage)`

Comment: @KevinB, the complete part is OK but my problem is with the error part.

Comment: @KevinB, status is error and message is Bad request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ?

```
       error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        switch (xhr.status) {
                            case 400:
                            case 401:
                            case 402:
                            case 403:
                            case 404:
                            case 500:
                                message = xhr.responseText;
                                break;
                            default :
                                message = 'Error unKnown';
                        }
       }
```

Comment: Yes, but the site says wait 4 minutes.